# GLSurfaceView, cannot find source

Tags: android

I'm working with examples that have worked fine in the past, but after no modification whatsoever, I am now getting this error from Eclipse.

```
GLSurfaceView, cannot find source
```

If I'm not mistaken this is an Android class correct? Has anyone else had this issue or know a known bug/solution?

I'm working in Android 2.2 BTW.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the emulator to test OpenGL ES 2 this will not work, the emulator does not currently support OpenGL ES 2.